# "Warning: Failed propType: Required prop 'fields' was not specified in 'ReduxForm(MyForm)'"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I've just added Redux to my React app and I thought it was working but now I keep getting two errors in my console.

This:

> Warning: Failed propType: Required prop 'fields' was not specified in
>   'ReduxForm(MyForm)'. Check the render method of
>   'Connect(ReduxForm(MyForm))'.

and this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined

The second refers to this (line 2):

```
var getValues = function getValues(fields, state) {
  return fields.reduce(function (accumulator, field) {
    getValue(field, state, accumulator);
    return accumulator;
  }, {});
};
```

**Upadte/Answer:**
Make sure redux-form is version 6 or higher

Comment: are you passing fields as a prop to the form?

Comment: You should define fields you will use in form `@reduxForm({
    form: 'some-id',
    fields: ['one', 'two']
  })`

Answer (score 0):

**Teach a man to fish!**

*You have not really given enough codes to go on.*

If fields are unexpectedly undefined then you should step through with chrome debugger or console.log everywhere. These are highly underrated methods!

1. In the browser hit the F12 key.
2. Select the Scripts , or Sources , tab in the developer tools.
3. Hit control+p and enter in the path to the file you are looking for.
       (Or located little folder icon in the top level to find your file.)
4. Add a breakpoint by clicking on the line number on the left (adds a
   little blue marker)
5. Execute your JavaScript.

Your code will run until it stops at the breakpoint and you can step forward from there. If you need to check every line then add breakpoints on all lines before stepping through. You can right click variables to add to watch list.

Keep going until you find a faulty logic, undefined/null, or bug occurs. Note that you can console.log() at any time from the console while the code is paused on a breakpoint and it will log correctly for variables in scope.